# Adding ads to my android app failing

Tags: android, gradle, ads

I am following some instructions, and I get this error.

> Error:Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0. Searched in the following locations: file:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/google/gms/google-services/3.0.0/google-services-3.0.0.pom file:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/google/gms/google-services/3.0.0/google-services-3.0.0.jar https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/google/gms/google-services/3.0.0/google-services-3.0.0.pom https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/google/gms/google-services/3.0.0/google-services-3.0.0.jar
>       Required by panic_android:app:unspecified

My gradle is:

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
   apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
   apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
 buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
}
 repositories {
mavenCentral()
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.netvariant.panic"
    minSdkVersion 15
    multiDexEnabled true
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.1"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    }
 }
 dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.13.1@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile 'com.skyfishjy.ripplebackground:library:1.0.1'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Comment: You have two `repositories` sections. Why? Or are those two files that you put together? And you seem to be missing `jCenter`

Comment: yes, adding jcenter solved the issue

Comment: You can use the checkmark next to my answer below to accept it

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing `jCenter()`

```
repositories {
    jCenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
 }
```